# Target.Address function not working

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code? I want to hide a set of rows by selecting a cell value from a drop down list (from cell D6). Is a simple trick but I can't make it work (this code is running in the destination sheet).

```
Private Sub change_View(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Address = "$D$6" Then
    If Target.Value = "Supervisor" Then Rows(14).Hidden = False
    If Target.Value = "Worker" Then Rows(14).Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `change_View` event, usually these type of things are implemented with `Worksheet_Change` event inside the relevant sheet.

I replaced your 2 x `If`s with a `Select Case`, in "case" you will need to add more scenarios in the future.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Range("D6"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Supervisor", "Worker"
             Rows(14).Hidden = True      
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai! Worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

I've this code, First one is working properly but second one doesn't :(

```
    If Target.Address = "$M$8" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                If Sheet1.Range("M8").Value2 = "LTA" Then
                Sheet1.Range("M6").Value2 = "Life-Class 3"
                Else
                End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$M$6" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                If Sheet1.Range("M6").Value2 = "Life-Class 2" Then
                Sheet1.Range("M8").Value2 = "DTA"
                Else
                End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
```

Is there any reason for that